# Some global variables are defined even at the start of a fresh session

Tags: bugs, version-10, kernel

In a fresh *Mathematica* session evaluating

```
Names["Global`*"]
```

doesn't give an empty list. The result is either

> ```
> {rhs, z}
> ```

or contains even more elements. Is this peculiar to Linux or does it happen as well in other platforms?